# "iso-mount seems to be mounted read-only" error in UCK 2.4.6 or 2.2.0

Tags: read-only, uck

I need to use [UCK](http://uck.sourceforge.net/) on 12.04. If I use any version of UCK 2.4.6 or UCK 2.2.0, I am getting an error

> iso-mount seems to be mounted read-only.

Can some one help to quickly sort this error? I need to use UCK on Lubuntu or Ubuntu 12.04 urgently.

Comment: When you get this error? Is it when you mount the Lubuntu or Ubuntu iso? Can you process ignoring this error

Comment: is your ISO on some ntfs drive with read only permission?

Comment: yes when i try to mount the iso it is giving this error. no i caanot process without ignoring this error.

Comment: no iso is not on ntfs. i am trying to mount iso with uck-remaster-unpack-iso as soon as i enter the command with root privileges it throws error Mounting ISO image...
mount: warning: ardd/remaster-iso-mount seems to be mounted read-only.

Comment: @SBarve that was a warning, can you proceed ignoring that?

Answer (score 1):

That is a just warning given by `mount` when an iso file is mounted.

UCK mounts the Ubuntu iso file in `~/tmp/remaster-iso-mount` directory so that directory name is part of the output. ***You can ignore that warning and you should.***

You can verify this by trying to manually mount the Ubuntu iso file. For the time being let's assume the file name is `ubuntu.iso` and it is in the current directory or home directory. Using this command

```
sudo mount ~/ubuntu.iso /mnt
```

would produce the warning below:

```
mount: warning: /mnt seems to be mounted read-only.
```

This is logical, because You can't mount an iso in read-write mode. An iso is always read-only.

Comment: but when i try to run a command uck-remaster-chroot-rootfs bash ubuntu.iso i am getting an error as "Remastering root directory does not exists"

Comment: @SBarve I used `ubuntu.iso` as an example, you may not have that file on your home dir. Also you should run `uck-gui` not `uck-remaster-chroot-rootfs` because, later command will work only when you did extract the iso, which is done by `uck-gui` automatically.

Comment: earlier i used to use uck without uck-gui and from command line i used to customize the iso easily.

Comment: I think you should change your ISO file's permissions.